# Custom sorting on array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array  `a=["Apple","Mango","apple","mango"]` .If I use the `a.sort()` the result is 
`["Apple", "Mango", "apple", "mango"]`

But What i desire is

```
Apple,apple,Mango,mango
```

Remember It is not case inSesitive search as whatever the order of given element in the array be ,the output should be as

**Apple**
**apple
Mango
mango**
Means the capital letter should precedes the smaller one

Comment: I think it has something to do with the case (_apple_ vs _Apple_).

Comment: have you considered writing your own compareFn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This

```
function alphabetical(a, b)
{
     var A = a.toLowerCase();
     var B = b.toLowerCase();
     if (A < B){
        return -1;
     }else if (A > B){
       return  1;
     }else{
       return 0;
     }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var colors = new Array("Apple","Mango","apple","mango");

colors.sort(alphabetical);

var cj = colors.join(", ");
alert(cj);
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/RcbeN/5/)

Comment: It is not case insensitive search, I updated my question...

Comment: my output is not same as you are desiring?

Comment: taking array as ("apple","Mango","Apple","mango") output (apple,Apple,Mango,mango) but it should be (Apple,apple,Mango,mango)

Comment: @Roshanjha check my updated demo

Comment: Sorry have asked this question again because this has been marked as duplicated.And your previous answer was not according to the requirement, Anyway thanks for your help